# Free RSS reader client for Mac with new post notification?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, rss

Is there any free RSS reader client for Mac that can give me a notification if there are new posts to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vienna](http://www.vienna-rss.org/).

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, [NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com/mac/) does this.

It's free, but ad-supported; you can pay extra to remove the ads.

Comment: Its a good RSS reader but It automatically refresh only after 30 mins... I need a reader that can refresh after 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

Use `Mail.app` and set it up as a filter in `Mail Preferences->RSS`.

Answer (score 1):

Though it will eventually be a paid app in the Mac App Store, the [Reeder beta](http://madeatgloria.com/brewery/silvio/reeder) is currently free. It's a very well-designed, highly polished app that's actually gotten me back into reading RSS feeds:

[image]

If you need a notification for new posts to read, you can configure Reeder to display a count of unread RSS items in the dock:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Google Chrome and the [Google Reader Notifier.](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lcepfljgpjnmoikmbedafopbakpjkijk)

Hopefully Google will build this in reader in the next update. Google Mail already has this build in.

Answer (score 0):

[NewsFire](http://www.newsfirerss.com/) has Growl integration.